# Mixture of types in generic list

Tags: .net, generics

I'm trying to do the following:

```
List<IRepository<IBusinessObject, ICriteria>> Repositories { get; }
```

and call this by

```
IRepository<ICustomer, ICustomerCriteria> cr = new CustomerRepository();

List.Add(CustomerRepository);
```

where ICustomer and ICustomerCriteria descend from IBusinessObject and ICriteria respectively.

However, this is not liked by the compiler.

Hmmm, I know I'm pushing it a bit, but I thought this would work?  Anyone know why?

Thanks
Duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [generic variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) problem:

This will illustrate the issue:

```
List<string> Strings = ...;
List<object> Objects = Strings; // Should work

Objects.Add(42); // 42 is an object - Should work
// But we would add an integer into a list of strings!!
```

In .NET FX 4, C# will support a special kind of `in` and `out` generic parameters to allow correct behavior.

Comment: Okay, but my object graph is sound - ICustomer descends from IBusinessObject, so I still don't see the problem!  Hmmm... any recommended workarounds then?

Comment: But you could add an `ICompletelyDifferentCriteria` into your list of `ICustomerCriteria` since both inherited `ICriteria`.

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't support covariance for generics. Consider this [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx)